# What are the acceptable strings for nsspeechsynthesizer's voiceName property in order to change the voice?

Tags: swift, appkit

I'm working through a tutorial in conjunction with Apple documentation and I'm attempting to change the voiceName of the NSSpeechSynthesizer however its init function says it accepts a string but I'm not sure of how to look up in the documentation to find the acceptable strings in order to change the voice.  [Apple NSSpeechSynthesizer Initialization Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1448381-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get available names in system

```
class var availableVoices: [NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceName] { get }
```

From [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1448470-availablevoices)  and pass any of them

Answer (score 1):

Get the available voices with

```
NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices
```

It returns an *Array of strings representing the identifiers of each voice available on the system.*